# Why is the widget not at the center of the window although it is in the center of the grid?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created a label, which I placed in the center row and center column of a grid:

```
label .mytext -text "Hello!"

grid x    x    x -in .
grid x .mytext x
grid x    x    x -in .

grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 1 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 2 -weight 1

grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . 1 -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . 2 -weight 1

wm geometry . 300x200
```

However, the label does not appear exactly at the center of the window; it is above the center:

[image: Screenshot of window created using Tcl/Tk]

Why is the label not exactly at the center of the window, even though I have placed it in the center of the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `grid x x x -in .` command effectively does nothing. The `grid x .mytext x` command puts the label in the first empty row, which is row 0. You can verify this with `grid info .mytext`.

To achieve what you seem to be trying, you can do:

```
label .mytext -text "Hello!"
grid .mytext -row 1 -column 1
grid rowconfigure . {0 1 2} -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . {0 1 2} -weight 1
wm geometry . 300x200
```

When doing it that way, the label does end up centered.

Comment: Strictly, leaving row and column 1 out of the weight setting will also center things. The weights affect the size of the cells, but widgets do not necessarily occupy the whole of their cell.